# Camunda page is not loading with K8s nginx rewrite annotation

Tags: nginx-ingress

I have camunda spring boot application deployed as K8s deployment and have 2 replicas running. To enable session affinity,  have configured K8s nginx. i am using rewrite annotation to to differentiate multiple microservices running. Below is my ingress resource definition and the url that am using to access the camunda page - http://:/sample/camunda/app/welcome/default/

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
   metadata:
   name: myservice
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "sample"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-port-in-redirects: "false"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /camunda/app/welcome/default/
    spec:
     rules:
    - http:
       paths:
       - backend:
           serviceName: myservice-service
           servicePort: 61055
         path: /sample
```

if I dont use rewrite annotation and use the below definition , it works fine with the url - http://:/camunda/app/welcome/default/

```
       apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
       kind: Ingress
      metadata:
         name: myservice
         annotations:
           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "sample"
           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
           nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-port-in-redirects: "false"    
       spec:
         rules:
         - http:
           paths:
            - backend:
              serviceName: myservice-service
              servicePort: 61055
             path: /
```

As I need to use different paths for different services, I had to go for rewrite annotation. But the camunda page is not loading if I use rewrite rule. Could you please suggest a solution?